# How to search for an XPath node within a Node object

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

I have the following program:

```
    package xpath;

    import java.io.StringReader;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.dom4j.Document;
    import org.dom4j.Node;
    import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

    public class TryXPath
    {
        public static void say(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

        public static String mainDocumentXML 
            = "<GetAvailableProductsResponse xmlns=\"http://api.onecommunications.com/pricing_availability/\">" + 
                "  <GetAvailableProductsResult>" + 
                "    <Products>" + 
                "      <Product>" + 
                "        <ProductID>101236004</ProductID>" + 
                "        <BaseProductName>Widget1</BaseProductName>" + 
                "      </Product>" + 
                "      <Product>" + 
                "        <ProductID>101236005</ProductID>" + 
                "        <BaseProductName>Widget2</BaseProductName>" + 
                "      </Product>" + 
                "      <Product>" + 
                "        <ProductID>101236006</ProductID>" + 
                "        <BaseProductName>Widget3</BaseProductName>" + 
                "      </Product>" + 
                "    </Products>" + 
                "  </GetAvailableProductsResult>" + 
                "</GetAvailableProductsResponse>";

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        String PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH = "/*[name()='GetAvailableProductsResponse']/*[name()='GetAvailableProductsResult']/*[name()='Products']";
        String PRODUCTS_PATH = "/*[name()='Product']";

            try
            {
                org.dom4j.io.SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

                Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(mainDocumentXML));
                Node root = document.selectSingleNode(PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH);
                if (root == null)
                {
                    say("No root");
                }
                else
                {
                    List<Node> productsNodeList = root.selectNodes(PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH + PRODUCTS_PATH);
                    say("products node list size=" + productsNodeList.size());
                    for (Node node : productsNodeList)
                    {
                        say("node: " + node.asXML());
                        say("name: " + node.getName());
                        say("id:   " + node.selectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='ProductID']").getText());
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

    }
```

It parses the given XML; one part produces a list of 3 Product nodes, and what I want to do then is access items within each node. However, the XPath expression for the ProductID that I'm using is incorrect ("//*[local-name()='ProductID']"); it evidently searches the main document, not the node on which the `selectSingleNode()` method is called.

Output from the program:

```
products node list size=3
node: <Product xmlns="http://api.onecommunications.com/pricing_availability/">        <ProductID>101236004</ProductID>        <BaseProductName>Widget1</BaseProductName>      </Product>
name: Product
id:   101236004
node: <Product xmlns="http://api.onecommunications.com/pricing_availability/">        <ProductID>101236005</ProductID>        <BaseProductName>Widget2</BaseProductName>      </Product>
name: Product
id:   101236004
node: <Product xmlns="http://api.onecommunications.com/pricing_availability/">        <ProductID>101236006</ProductID>        <BaseProductName>Widget3</BaseProductName>      </Product>
name: Product
id:   101236004
```

Note that all the values for "id" are from the first node, instead of being the ProductID values for the node on which `selectSingleNode()` is called.

I've tried all kinds of combinations of ".", "/", no "/", "::", etc., and I cannot seem to find the XPath expression that will return the ProductID node within a single Product node in the list. How do I do that?

Comment: It's also possible that the program doesn't have access to the namespace, so I've been playing with local-name as well.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that '//' in the string "//*[local-name()='ProductID']") will find all ProductIDs no matter where they are in the document. When used with the selectSingleNode() method, you will always get the first one on the set.

What you really want to do is selectNodes() on the 'ProductID' path and iterate over those.  You can even get the associated 'BaseProductName' associated with the 'ProductID' by doing some relative calls (see below).

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH = "/*[name()='GetAvailableProductsResponse']/*[name()='GetAvailableProductsResult']/*[name()='Products']";

    try {
        org.dom4j.io.SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();

        Document document = reader.read(new StringReader(mainDocumentXML));
        Node root = document.selectSingleNode(PRODUCTS_NODE_PATH);
        if (root == null) {
            say("No root");
        } else {

            // [JIM]  Get all the ProductID nodes               
            List<Node> productsNodeList = root.selectNodes("./*[local-name()='Product']/*[local-name()='ProductID']");              

            // [JIM] Now iterate through and pull out the values
            say("products node list size=" + productsNodeList.size());
            for (Node node : productsNodeList) {
                say(node.getText());
                // [JIM] Get the associated BaseProductName relative to the current ProductID
                say(node.getParent().selectSingleNode("./*[local-name()='BaseProductName']").getText());
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the output when I run this solution:

products node list size=3
101236004
Widget1
101236005
Widget2
101236006
Widget3